# Looking for orange tyres

Tags: road-bike, tire, product-rec

I'm looking for a pair of folding, *orange* training tires, size should be 700x23C.

I'd like to have only an orange stripe, not the whole tire.

Can you recommend some model?

Comment: Related: [This thread](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/205/bike-building-questions) in meta.

Comment: Ok, I agree it was a silly question.

Comment: It's not silly, there's just some disagreement about whether or not it fits in with the site. Welcome to bicyeles.se and please keep asking questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the Michelin Pro 3. 700 x 23c, folding bead.

[image]

http://www.biketiresdirect.com/product/michelin-pro3-race-tire

Comment: how did you find these? A google search didn't work for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me either, that's why I was asking :)

Comment: "orange tire folding 700 x 23c" on google images ( http://www.google.ca/images?q=orange+tire+folding+700+x+23c&hl=fr&biw=1366&bih=668&gbv=2&tbs=isch:1&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=ZrzvTOzzEoWClAfQ0IX-CQ&ved=0CBIQpwU ). It was somewhere in there. ;) You can also refine searches by the colour of the image ( http://www.google.ca/images?q=orange+tire+folding+700+x+23c&hl=fr&biw=1366&bih=668&gbv=2&tbs=isch:1,ic:specific,isc:orange&source=lnt ) but that returned only completely orange tires.

Answer (score 5):

The Vittoria Rubino Pro's have a kevlar bead (foldable) and in the past I have found them to be excellent value for money.  Maybe too much orange?

[image: Orange Rubino Pro]

Answer (score 4):

A little googling goes a long way...

I didn't realize that one of my favorite tires (Continental Grand Prix) comes in many colors, including orange:

[image]

Tufo also makes sweet tires, some in orange:

[image]

Also see the Vredstein Fortezza Tricomp 
[image]

Comment: if you just want stripes on the side, either ride through some fresh asphalt or hold a black marker to the tire while riding.